# AppCompatImageView displaying big image using ScaleType.CENTER and the use of padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an image 3264x1836 and I display it in a custom AppCompatImageView having dimensions 1280x720. I want to preserve the image size so I use `ScaleType.CENTER`, but I also want that its top-left corner is positioned at the coordinates 0,0 of my custom view, so I set the padding left and top accordingly.
Now, to achieve that I had to use 3264-1280 (the difference between the widths) as left padding and 1836-720 (the difference between the heights) as top padding while, in my opinion, these values should be both divided by 2.
Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>It is likely that you are breaking the *AppCompatImageView* code by asking it to do something that wasn't anticipated or tested.</s>

While the above could still be true, the padding that you are applying is correct. Here are the calculations:

For simplicity, let's take a look at the left padding needed to shift the graphic. The same sort of calculations will work for the top padding.

The width of the graphic is greater than the width of the *ImageView*.

d = w<sub>graphic</sub> - w<sub>imageview</sub>

If the graphic is centered in the *ImageView*, then the overhang on the left and right sides will be 1/2 the difference in widths.

s = d / 2

The graphic is centered within the padding of the *ImageView*. The amount of padding that has to be specified must be just enough to shift the center of the graphic by the amount *s*.

The initial center of the *ImageView* without padding is

c<sub>i</sub> = w<sub>imageview</sub> / 2

The shifted center with left padding ( p ) is

c<sub>s</sub> = p + (w<sub>imageview</sub> - p) / 2

So,

s = c<sub>s</sub> - c<sub>i</sub> = p + (w<sub>imageview</sub> - p) / 2  - (w<sub>imageview</sub> / 2)

Solving for the padding needed for a shift of s we get p = 2s = d. In other words, the padding we need is twice the shift required which is what you are seeing.

A fix that doesn't involve padding would be to specify

```
 android:scaleType="matrix"
```

You should remove the padding. The new scale type will apply the identity matrix to the image and place it in the top/left corner without resizing.

Comment: I played a bit around your solution and it does what it has to do but it's not good for me. Indeed my aim is much more complex of what I explained in my question where I tried to simplify. I need to switch between a ScaleType.CENTER_CROP view and one of the four corner-zoom view. Matrix is good for the left-top corner but not for the other three where neither the use of padding nor the use of translate() work.
Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Luca So, I answered your question as stated, but you needed an answer to a question that you did not ask.

Comment: The question was "Can somebody explain why?" and not "Can somebody suggest an alternative?". But that is just useless clarification. Instead, more important, I worked more on the matrix together with setTranslate and setScale and found out a clean and more elegant solution. In conclusion you answered the question and suggested a valid alternative too, good job!